# Boost ptime under MinGW not thread safe

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I have a problem with boost library. I'm using MinGW with gcc 4.5.2 to compile the following code:

```
unsigned long GetEpochSeconds()
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    using namespace boost::gregorian;

    ptime now(second_clock::universal_time());
    ptime epoch(date(1970,1,1));
    time_duration diff = now-epoch;
    return diff.total_seconds();
}
```

The problem is that this code is not thread-safe. When I run it from within multiple threads, my application crashes. For now I've converted to c-standard functions like time, mktime etc. and everything works fine, but in the future I will need a few boost time functions.

I was compiling also with -D_REENTRANT, but this didn't help.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: did you compile everything with `-mthreads` as well?

Comment: You could wrap it in a mutex if the performance hit isn't too great.

Comment: Can you narrow down your example, and show complete code which causes the crash? Also, what kind of crash? Where does it happen?

Comment: +1. Thanks for posting this. You may want to report to Boost :)

Comment: It is not only MinGW that is affected, even Visual Studio builds are affected, as `localtime_r` and `gmtime_r` isn't supported. In Visual Studio the functions `localtime_s` and `gmtime_s` could be used, but they aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your code is calling gmtime() or gmtime_r() (use a debugger for this).  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/date_time/c_time.hpp and note that BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_REENTRANT_STD_FUNCTIONS must be defined in order for getting the time to be thread-safe.

Comment: It's really sad/bad that the implementation doesn't use `localtime_s` and `gmtime_s` in Visual Studio...

Comment: @dalle: I don't know much about Windows programming, but it is interesting that they even go to the trouble of disabling compiler warnings in order to use the non-_s functions.  Why don't you submit a patch, or at least propose the change on the Boost mailing list?

Comment: Looking at the code the regular `localtime` and `gmtime` functions are thread safe using Visual Studio CRT libraries. They are not reentrant, but each thread use their own internal `struct tm` buffer.

Comment: I agree.  Still, some people might prefer to use the _s versions of those functions on Windows (again, I'm no expert there, I'm just going by a glance at the MS docs).